# angular 6 post **array data** using `httpClient` method is not working with asp.net core API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0

I,m Fresher to dot-net and angular technologies,and am trying to post the **array** of data using  angular-6 `httpClient` method but I'm failing to hit the HTTP Post API method(found by using break-point). please help me to find what is the error.

component method call the service

```
let selectedLanguageList: userChoosenQC[] = [];

this.quizzerService.InsertUserChoosenDetails(selectedLanguageList)
.subscribe((data) => {});
```

**service class method to call the API**

```
InsertUserChoosenDetails(data: userChoosenQC[]): any {
     const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) };
var details = this.httpClient.post<userChoosenQC[]>(this.apiUrl + '/Questions/InsertUserLikes',
     data, httpOptions);
    return details;}
```

`userChoosenQC` interface type

```
export interface userChoosenQC{
      Id :number
     QuizType :number; 
     QuizzerDetails :number 
     QuizQuestions:number; 
     QuizChoices :number; 
}
```

I'm failed to hit this HTTP-POST API Method

```
[HttpPost, Route("InsertUserLikes")]
        public ActionResult InsertUserSelections(List<QuizzerQCdetails> userSelectedQC)
        {
            userRepository.InsertUserSelectedQC(userSelectedQC);


return Ok(new { res="data Inserted sucessfully" });
    }``
```

`QuizzerQCdetails` POCO class

```
public class QuizzerQCdetails
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public QuizType quizType { get; set; }
        public QuizzerDetails quizzerDetails { get; set; }
        public QuizQuestions quizQuestions { get; set; }
        public QuizChoices quizChoices { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm getting this error

> HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed"

Comment: what error do you see on server side?

Comment: I didn't see any error in server side the api is not hitting .

Comment: Can you share any  code snippets to **post list or array**  of data using angular-6 with asp.net api core, that may help to understand my code errors

Comment: What is `QuizType`, `QuizzerDetails` and etc?  You are passing `userChoosenQC ` with number properties, but you received model seems to be inrelevant.

Comment: Try to share us your network tab and error in your web browser developer tool. Are your client and web api in the same project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this error, it seems to be failed by cors issue. Try to configure CORS in web api like

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com")
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });
```

and

```
app.UseCors();
```

In addition, not sure your current Controller code, try to add `FromBody`

```
    [HttpPost, Route("InsertUserLikes")]
    public ActionResult InsertUserSelections([FromBody]List<QuizzerQCdetails> userSelectedQC)
```